# Extending div past parent container while keeping child div within container

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This doesn't seem like it should be a difficult problem but I can't think of a workable solution.

I want to have a div that extends beyond its parent container (using Bootstrap 3, so an 1170px max width container) from the left side of the page. Within that, I need another centered container, so the text and button within don't extend past 1170px.

Here's a screenshot of what I need to achieve:

http://postimg.org/image/3x9s5cnr1/

EDIT: I don't think I was as clear as I could have been about what I was trying to achieve. The absolute positioning on the white div behind the text was just to keep the div extended beyond the container to the left side of the window, but it wasn't crucial. The goal was just to keep the text and button within a centered container, but have the white div around the text and button extend to the left side of the window. I edited the question to make it a bit more clear.

Anyway, I came up with a simple method that works. I just used:

```
margin-left: -9999px
padding-left: 9999px
```

on the white div to keep it extended left, without using absolute positioning. It still doesn't seem 'correct' to me but works fine.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: What you're saying you're trying to do and what the image you posted shows are 2 different things. The text and button are left aligned inside the translucent container. It's just that the container has a gradient so it's transparent at the far left

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539423/bootstrap-column-to-extend-out-side-of-the-container

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying about the gradient, but I agree that the question was a bit unclear. I edited it and added my solution, which probably isn't ideal but works.

Answer (score 0):

Set the child div to

```css
div.parent {
position:absolute;
background:#ccc;
left:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

div.child {
position: relative;
left: 25%;
background: #fff;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll have to adjust height/width and alter the top/left percentages based upon your preferences. The key is having a relative container within the absolute one to

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of the child container and want

to horizontally center the div, do

```
position: relative;
left:50%;
margin-left:-childContainerWidth/2;
```

or to center the div, do

```
position: relative;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

If it's a case of centering with unknown width/height, you can try this [guide](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)